# ¿Por qué "mear fuera del tiesto" es "decir algo que no viene al caso"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, locuciones

En el DLE encontramos:

[**mear**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ohxly6r)

> intr. malson. **orinar** (‖ expeler la orina).

[**tiesto**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZjD1ubu)

> 1. m. **Pedazo de cualquier vasija de barro.**
>   2. m. **maceta** (‖ recipiente de barro para criar plantas).
>   3. m. *Bol., Chile y Hond.* **Vasija de cualquier clase**.
>   4. m. desus. **cráneo**.

[**mear fuera del tiesto**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZjD1ubu)

> 1. loc. verb. coloq. **Salirse de la cuestión, decir algo que no viene al caso.**

que no parece tener ninguna relación clara ni con **mear** ni con **tiesto**. ¿Cómo se ha formado esa locución con ese sentido?

Por lo que he visto en el NTLLE, la RAE lo recoge por primera vez en el diccionario de 1925.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La raíz de esta expresión está en el origen de otras similares como la genérica *hacer algo fuera de lugar*. Hay cosas que tienen su lugar y no otro, y hacerlas fuera de ese lugar es inapropiado.

Según leo en varias fuentes, ninguna de las cuales es necesariamente confiable, en Castilla se solía llamar *tiesto* al [orinal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RDo9Pya) (recipiente portátil para orinar y defecar). Esto hace que la expresión tenga un poco más de sentido que si *tiesto* significara sólo "maceta" (recipiente para plantas) o "vasija" en general, pero no es necesario para crear la imagen figurativa deseada.

Los hombres tenemos la suerte de poder apuntar al orinar, pero eso requiere un mínimo de atención. Orinar fuera del lugar correspondiente indica que uno no presta atención a lo que hace, o no tiene control sobre sí mismo, o se sale de las normas mínimas de cuidado o cortesía que exige la sociedad (entre las cuales está hacer sus necesidades fisiológicas en ciertos lugares).

En español americano (donde *tiesto* suele ser reemplazado por *tarro*) hablamos similarmente de *desubicarse*, sentido que no está contemplado en el DLE (que sólo menciona los significados literales de *[desubicar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DWFbXOL)*). De nuevo, se trata de equiparar falta de orientación (o puntería) con falta de sentido común o de la oportunidad para hablar.